# Why do I get undefined constructor

Tags: javascript

I try to follow Stephan Stoyanov book on JavaScript Design Patterns. And one of the examples in this book looks similar to this:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    var Constr, cnt = 0;
    Constr = function () {};    
    Constr.id = function () {
        return "myid-" + cnt;
    };
    Constr.prototype = {
        constructor: MyClass // <-- Please, pay attention
    };
    return Constr;
}());
```

However, when I use this code like so:

```
var tst = new MyClass();
console.log(tst.contructor);
```

I see `undefined` in the console. Why is that and how can I fix that?

Comment: Look at the order that code runs in. The function is executed. Then a value a returned. Then that value is assigned to `MyClass`.

Comment: I see the very same order in the book. Can you, please, elaborate on this a little bit?

Comment: Looks like an error in the book. What's to elaborate? It's a very simple problem.

Comment: I checked the book, and it seems like it does not have an error. The author first creates a namespace MYAPP.utilities.Array and then uses it as a constructor - constructor: MYAPP.utilities.Array. Whereas in my case, MyClass does not exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point you assign `MyClass` to the `.constructor` property of the prototype, the variable `MyClass` has not yet been initialized.  It won't have a value until after your function is done executing.  Instead, you can just assign it `Constr` since that does have a value and they will be the same value that is eventually assigned to `MyClass`.

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    var Constr, cnt = 0;
    Constr = function () {};    
    Constr.id = function () {
        return "myid-" + cnt;
    };
    Constr.prototype = {
        constructor: Constr // <-- Change to this
    };
    return Constr;
}());
```

Comment: @Jacobian - I still don't think the `cnt` variable is doing what you want.  There's really no point in having it there at all because it is only ever referenced once when the IIFE is first run and is never referenced again.  I hate seeing people use this construct when its features are not needed.  IMO, code should be as simple as possible to meet its objective.  This example is NOT that.

Comment: Actually, it's a minified code. In real version I have cnt++. By the way, I tested your version and still get undefined, when I check constructor.

Comment: @Jacobian - my point is that even if you're using `cnt++` that doesn't change things.  That outer function that contains `cnt` is never executed more than once and it is not being used as a closure so it's just extra code in the way of a more simplified expression.  If you refered to `cnt` inside the `Constr` function definition, then it would be a potentially-useful closure.  Nothing wrong with learning these constructs for the cases they could be useful, but I hate seeing people use them for a standard simple object definition that does not need the extra complexity.

Comment: I plan to use it statically, like in ExtJS library - Ext.id(). In my case it would be MyClass.id(). And in functions that create instances I would increment this cnt variable.

Comment: "That outer function that contains cnt is never executed more than once". The catch is, it is used more than once - in fact every time when some instances are created. And this static MyClass.id() is a way to provide unique ids for all instances across the application. But if you have another idea and some arguments, it would be greate to hear them. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacobian - Not sure you understand what happens here.  That outer function is executed the first time and then after that, `MyClass` contains a reference to `Constr`.  So, when you do `new MyClass()`, you're calling `Constr`, not executing the outer function again.  The outer function just serves as a closure that holds variables that `Constr()` or `Constr.id()` can reference which is a useful technique if you're actually using those.  The code in your question was simplified to where it was not actually using the closure productively, but if you are then this is a fine construct for that.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
     Constr.prototype = {
         constructor: MyClass // MyClass is undefined right now!
     };
```

The function hasn't completed when it assigns MyClass as the value for the constructor property. At this point MyClass is undefined, so that's what you get.

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/vh45can8/

Answer (score 1):

As written `Constr` is an anonymous function which already has its prototype object's constructor pointing to itself. I hope the book gives a reason for making things complicated:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    var Constr, cnt = 0;
    Constr = function () {};    
    Constr.id = function () {
        return "myid-" + cnt;
    };
    return Constr;
}());
```

works without serious mystery.

Comment: There is some modification in the book. The author first creates a namespace, and then uses it. So, that instead of MyClass variable as in my case, in the book there is MYAPP.utilities.Array object, that already exists.