# Returning the ID of MyClass in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

I have this block of code that will create a new instance of `MyClass`, I want each instances of this class to have an id. So I have a function that will return cnt, and every time the new object is initialized the id value will increase.

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    var Constr, cnt = 0;

    Constr = function () {};    
    Constr.id = function () {
    return cnt;
    };

    Constr.prototype = {
        constructor: Constr, 
        id: Constr.id
    };
    cnt++
    return Constr;
}());

var x = new MyClass();
console.log(x.id);
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = x.id;
```

The problem is, I obviously want the value of `cnt` to be returned, but everything I do returns `function() { return cnt; }`

Update, deleted fiddle, posted incorrect one.

Comment: This question shows that you didn't really understand [my comments on your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117933/why-do-i-get-undefined-constructor/35118044#35118044) about the outer function only getting called once.  I'd suggest you reread those.  When you do `x = new MyClass()` it is ONLY executing the `Constr` function, nothing else.

Comment: I was not the original asker. I saw the code, and started playing with it.

Comment: Answers here on stack overflow should NOT be updated to include the answer.  That is not the way stack overflow works.  Questions should stay questions.  You should select the best answer you were provided (with the green checkmark) as an indication to the community of which answer you thought worked best for you.

Comment: OK, sorry I saw the same code and assumed same person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each instance to have a unique value, then you need to set that value in the constructor for the instance.

You can't inherit the value on the prototype chain. That is what you do when you want every object to have the same value.

You also need to assign the value you want and not a function which will return the value.

```
Constr = function () {
    this.id = cnd;
};
```

Comment: Now, I just got completely lost. I can't seem to get the id to increase. https://jsfiddle.net/hkj7t8je/4/

Comment: @christopherclark — You increment `cnt` once, when you run the IIFE that scopes all the bits of the constructor function. You need to increment it each time you create a new instance. i.e. inside the constructor function.

Comment: Success! I'll update my post to include the answer. But what is the point of having `Constr.id = function () { return cnt;};` If this will never return any value?

Comment: @christopherclark — No point at all that I can see, but you wrote it, not me. That's why I said to assign a value to `id` in the constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the id to be uniquely assigned for each new instance of your class, then you need to assign the id to your instance data in the `Const` constructor:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    var cnt = 0;

    // constructor for our object    
    function Constr() {
        // assign a unique id to this object when it is created
        this.id = cnt++;
    };

    // static method (not an instance method) - get current global cnt value 
    Constr.id = function () {
       return cnt;
    };

    Constr.prototype = {
        constructor: Constr, 
    };
    return Constr;
}());

var x = new MyClass();
console.log(x.id);
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = x.id;
```

---

This question shows that perhaps you didn't really understand [my comments on your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117933/why-do-i-get-undefined-constructor/35118044#35118044) about the outer function only getting called once.  I'd suggest you reread those.

When you do:

```
x = new MyClass()
```

it is ONLY executing the `Constr` function, nothing else.  Plus, the `.prototype` is shared among all instances (that is the point of it) so you can never put a counter there that is unique for each instance.

Comment: `Constr.id = function() { return cnt;};` did not return any value, it just replicated the function

Comment: @christopherclark - That function is only needed if you ever wanted to "see" what the current value of the global `cnt` was.  It's a static method, not attached to any particular object.  You had it in your code.  I just added a comment in my answer for what it actually does.  A particular instance count is accessed via the `x.id` property.

Comment: Ahh, you call that with MyClass.id()!

Comment: @christopherclark - Yes, now you're getting it.  Using OO terminology, that's a "class static" method.

Answer (score -1):

It seem like all You need is:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    var cnt = 0;

    function Constr() {
      this.id = cnt++;
    };    

    Constr.prototype = {
      constructor: Constr
    };

    return Constr;
}());
```

---

The following one was my previous BAD answer,

You could replace Constr.id with:

```
....
Constr.id = new function () {
  this.toString = function () {
    return ++cnt;
  }
};
....
```

and then You should get it from the instance with

```
var x = new MyClass();
console.debug(x.id);
```

but take care that it will be an object and only when used as a string, (like in console.debug, or with .innerHTML= "..." ) will be a string.
Hope it helps.

Comment: `Constr.id` is a static property (a property on the constructor).  It has nothing to do with `x.id` (an instance property).

Comment: From Your description the static function is not useful at all

Comment: Yeah, I think the OP did not understand what it did or did not do (it was copied from code in another question).  It isn't particularly useful here.